# Reading exe in windows c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am planning to create a Licensing Module which can be commonly used for all Desktop Applications. So i thought of making it so simple without any or less coding in the existing applications which are going to be activated by this Licensing Module.

So is there any way where if the user passes the exe location, the system should capture the exe available in the particular location, and the system should get all the windows forms available inside that exe?

Am not sure whether it is possible or not but i need to know whether there is any way to do it. It would be helpful for me to develop this with less complications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found a solution for this....i used the following method...

```
            Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly path here");

            // Display all the types contained in the specified assembly.
            foreach (Type oType in SampleAssembly.GetTypes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oType.Name);
            }
```

this worked perfectly for me....

VinayC thanks for your support buddy...really appreciate it....:)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the actual executable image data from its path and in case, its a managed (.NET) executable, you can use the metadata to do some analysis. In this case, you can browse through all types within the executable assembly (and perhaps other assemblies from the same directory) and find out the number of classes/types that are inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

However, considering that these applications are probably in your control, the saner approach would be have an public API in these executable that will provide you the relevant information.

Comment: an even more sane approach would be not trying to create what I'm guessing is going to be a convoluted licensing system in the first place. ;)